# jQuery Selector - Check if current div attribute contains text?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, attributes

My code is looping through some divs and I'm trying to find the one that contains certain text in its style attribute. This is my best attempt, but it doesn't find it.

```
$("#RootDiv > div").each(function (index)
{
    if ($(this).is("[style~='bg-stripes.gif']"))
            alert("found");
});
```

Html

```
<div id="RootDiv">
<div style="background-color: White;"></div>
<div style="background-image: url(bg-stripes.gif);"></div>
<div style="background-color: White;"></div></div>
```

Comment: What does the HTML look like?

Comment: particular text, or any text?

Comment: Have you tried `if ($(this).attr('style').indexOf('...') > -1 )`?

Comment: Does `$(this).is("[style*='bg-stripes.gif']")` work better?  `~=` finds by entire word rather than just substring.

Comment: @nbrooks Whoops, added.  I r bad at SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @FelixKling says you dont need to use a selector, I think using selectors is more confusing in this particular case, instead you can simply try:

```
if ($(this).attr('style').indexOf('bg-stripes.gif') > -1 )
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `*=` selector instead:

```
$(this).is("[style*='bg-stripes.gif']")
```

The `~=` selector will only work with individual words rather than substrings.

Answer (score 0):

The `~=` operator looks for space-separated words, which is probably unsuitable for the `style` attribute.

Try using the `*=` "contains" operator instead.  You can also combine this in the original selector:

```
$("#RootDiv > div[style*='bg-stripes.gif']")...
```

which will give you exactly the elements you need without you having to iterate over them and testing them with `.is()` individually.

Comment: thanks, this works also. I do have to iterate though, i just left out some code to simplify my question.

Comment: @user2174420 sure, so still use `.each`, but leave out the `if` test - on modern browsers this _should_ be more efficient.

Comment: ok, I get what you're saying, but i do need to loop through all the divs because I'm using them in my code (not shown) as well. Thanks!

Comment: are you only using the matching elements, or do you have other `if` conditions that match other elements?